# How to stop and start a systemd service via python script w/o requiring sudo password

Tags: python, service

The following script allows me to check whether a `systemd service` is active, and to stop or start the service. When executing `.stop()` or `.start()`, **how can I proceed to stopping and starting the service directly w/o having to  supply the sudo password?** An example application of where this is useful is stopping and restarting the `NetworkManager` service.

```
#!/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys


class SystemdService(object):
    '''A systemd service object with methods to check it's activity, and to stop() and start() it.'''

    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service


    def is_active(self):
        """Return True if systemd service is running"""
        try:
            cmd = '/bin/systemctl status {}.service'.format(self.service)
            completed = subprocess.run( cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
            print( 'ERROR:', err )
        else:
            for line in completed.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
                if 'Active:' in line:
                    if '(running)' in line:
                        print('True')
                        return True
            return False


    def stop(self):
        ''' Stop systemd service.'''
        try:
            cmd = '/bin/systemctl stop {}.service'.format(self.service)
            completed = subprocess.run( cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
            print( 'ERROR:', err )


    def start(self):
        ''' Start systemd service.'''
        try:
            cmd = '/bin/systemctl start {}.service'.format(self.service)
            completed = subprocess.run( cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
            print( 'ERROR:', err )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = SystemdService(sys.argv[1])
    monitor.is_active()
```

Comment: Did [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password) not help?

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks for the link. I noticed the recommended  procedures still required sudo permission... I am working towards creating a pypi application that when installed would enable a systemd service. How do I implement those sudo permission settings described in the link?

Answer (score -1):

Works for me just as your script is. It's like your question has a solution in itself.
In the terminal, you can start, stop, restart a service with the following command example: sudo systemctl restart "name of service".service. To achieve the same via python script, the above command example becomes: /bin/systemctl restart "name of service".service